# Rdlc report column rearrange i want to shift first column to last . Please

Tags: .net

i want to bring this column to last in Rdlc report

there are four columns in my report and i want to bring first grouping column to last column of my report.

image link on this http://tinypic.com/r/2ezjndi/8

this is my report XML file.

```
  <Tablix Name="Tablix6">
    <TablixCorner>
      <TablixCornerRows>
        <TablixCornerRow>
          <TablixCornerCell>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="Textbox88">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                  <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                      <TextRun>
                        <Value>Group1</Value>
                        <Style />
                      </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style />
                  </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox88</rd:DefaultName>
                <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
              </Textbox>
            </CellContents>
          </TablixCornerCell>
          <TablixCornerCell>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="Textbox80">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                  <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                      <TextRun>
                        <Value>Participant Name</Value>
                        <Style />
                      </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style />
                  </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox80</rd:DefaultName>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
              </Textbox>
            </CellContents>
          </TablixCornerCell>
        </TablixCornerRow>
      </TablixCornerRows>
    </TablixCorner>
    <TablixBody>
      <TablixColumns>
        <TablixColumn>
          <Width>1.10208in</Width>
        </TablixColumn>
        <TablixColumn>
          <Width>1.10208in</Width>
        </TablixColumn>
        <TablixColumn>
          <Width>1in</Width>
        </TablixColumn>
      </TablixColumns>
      <TablixRows>
        <TablixRow>
          <Height>0.375in</Height>
          <TablixCells>
            <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="A">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value>=Sum(Fields!A.Value)</Value>
                          <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>A</rd:DefaultName>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                      <Style>Solid</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
            <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="B">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value>=Sum(Fields!B.Value)</Value>
                          <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>B</rd:DefaultName>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                      <Style>Solid</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
            <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="Notes1">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value>=Fields!Notes.Value</Value>
                          <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>Notes1</rd:DefaultName>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                      <Style>Solid</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
          </TablixCells>
        </TablixRow>
        <TablixRow>
          <Height>0.375in</Height>
          <TablixCells>
            <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="A1">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value>=Sum(Fields!A.Value)</Value>
                          <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>A1</rd:DefaultName>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                      <Style>Solid</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
            <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="B1">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value>=Sum(Fields!B.Value)</Value>
                          <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>B1</rd:DefaultName>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                      <Style>Solid</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
            <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="Textbox141">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value />
                          <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>Textbox141</rd:DefaultName>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                      <Style>Solid</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
                <rd:Selected>true</rd:Selected>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
          </TablixCells>
        </TablixRow>
      </TablixRows>
    </TablixBody>
    <TablixColumnHierarchy>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember>
          <TablixHeader>
            <Size>0.375in</Size>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="Textbox104">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                  <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                      <TextRun>
                        <Value />
                        <Style />
                      </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style />
                  </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox104</rd:DefaultName>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
              </Textbox>
            </CellContents>
          </TablixHeader>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <TablixHeader>
            <Size>0.375in</Size>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="Textbox93">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                  <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                      <TextRun>
                        <Value>B</Value>
                        <Style />
                      </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style />
                  </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox93</rd:DefaultName>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
              </Textbox>
            </CellContents>
          </TablixHeader>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <TablixHeader>
            <Size>0.375in</Size>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="Textbox140">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                  <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                      <TextRun>
                        <Value>Notes</Value>
                        <Style />
                      </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style />
                  </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox140</rd:DefaultName>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
              </Textbox>
            </CellContents>
          </TablixHeader>
        </TablixMember>
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixColumnHierarchy>
    <TablixRowHierarchy>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember>
          <Group Name="Group1">
            <GroupExpressions>
              <GroupExpression>=Fields!CriteriaText.Value</GroupExpression>
            </GroupExpressions>
            <Parent>=Fields!CriteriaText.Value</Parent>
          </Group>
          <SortExpressions>
            <SortExpression>
              <Value>=Fields!CriteriaText.Value</Value>
            </SortExpression>
          </SortExpressions>
          <TablixHeader>
            <Size>1.10208in</Size>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="Notes">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                  <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                      <TextRun>
                        <Value>=Fields!Notes.Value</Value>
                        <Style />
                      </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style />
                  </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Notes</rd:DefaultName>
                <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
              </Textbox>
            </CellContents>
          </TablixHeader>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>1.10208in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="CriteriaText">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!CriteriaText.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>CriteriaText</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="ParticipantName">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!ParticipantName.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Group>
              <SortExpressions>
                <SortExpression>
                  <Value>=Fields!ParticipantName.Value</Value>
                </SortExpression>
              </SortExpressions>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>1.10208in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="ParticipantName">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!ParticipantName.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>ParticipantName</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixMember>
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixRowHierarchy>
    <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
    <Top>0.41333in</Top>
    <Left>0.65292in</Left>
    <Height>1.125in</Height>
    <Width>5.40833in</Width>
    <Style>
      <Border>
        <Style>None</Style>
      </Border>
    </Style>
  </Tablix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just work with your XML file - should be a matter of simple cut + paste.

Comment: I have tried a lot, but didn't get success. i try to replace  <TablixCorner> from first to end but not get success

Comment: If you add Tablix portion from your rdlc XML into your question, maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: MAINLY I WANT TO MERGE vertical column.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I don't think it can be done. I played with it for a bit and though you can just add this "Group1" column at the end, but you cannot really merge vertical cells the way you want - on the right side.

Comment: There is no alternate way for this ?

Comment: All I can think of is nesting table into table (both with the same dataset) and setting filters for data in nested table. This way you can have your right column to expand to fit all data. Columns on the left would be added to "parent" table, then cells merged in the row, and then insert table into this "merged cell" and align columns to parent's table columns.

Comment: can you give me example ?